# Rails4: How to generate hashed paths with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, hash, carrierwave

I'm using Rails4 and Carrierwave to upload files, and I have it working.
I have come to use hashed paths to store images after reading the aritcle, [Store attachments in hashed paths](http://makandracards.com/makandra/734-deliver-paperclip-attachments-to-authorized-users-only).

I would like to save my files with paths like this: `public\uploads\a0190f068\47fab52d31\82d24bb\9b4d6f.jpg` instead of `public\uploads\photo\image\156\filename.jpg` with carrierwave.

Any suggestions or exercises for doing this are appreciated.

\uploaders\image_uploader.rb

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::RMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_fill => [150, 150]
   end

end
```

\views\articles\ _article.html.erb

```
    <% article.photos.each do |photo| %>
      <%= image_tag(photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s, class: :thumb) if photo.image? %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: you could try hash function from [Digest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-trunk/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest.html) with `hexdigest` method

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @IS04. I tried `Digest::MD5.hexdigest` and it works.